# caching in browser without .htaccess file

Tags: java, html

This is Code
image should be cached
how do i cache above image either in java code or in browser without .htacess file

```
       <HTML>
<head></head>
<BODY>
<div><img src="banner1.png"/></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Above is my sample html code and i want that image to be cached in browser after first request to the server . And  my application is written in java technology (apache Wicket)

Comment: You need to implement caching on your server. If you are using Apache then look into Apache mods for caching. If you have a Java servlet and your code is generated from JSP (or server side app) then use the facilities in the framework to implement caching headers. HTML itself is not enough to define caching rules as those rules are part of HTTP response headers.

Comment: i wrote setHeaders() code in my java program but no use still the image is loading from server .Here is my java code                WebResponse response = getWebRequestCycle().getWebResponse();
  
   response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000,must-revalidate");
   response.setHeader("pragma", "max-age=31536000");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a huge difference whether a browser caches a file or whether you cache a file in your application.

For caching on the server side, you should first check whether your web server, your application container or your web applications framework offers caching. If not, you might want to use a caching framework (e.g. ehcache) or implement yourself just what you need.

Caching in the Browser will usually happen without any configuration on your side (assuming it's e.g. a static file etc.).

Comment: okay fine thanks ! but when i do request to my server the image is loading from server each time and it is reducing server performance.how do i solve this problem ?(and my code is written i  java (Frame work Apache Wicket))

Comment: and i also added setHeader() in my code but its not making any differences

Comment: Here is my java code WebResponse response = getWebRequestCycle().getWebResponse(); response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000,must-revalidate"); response.setHeader("pragma", "max-age=31536000");